# How to disable the / character prefix in Cyrillic input mode?

Tags: input-method, quail

When I switch to Cyrillic input method (by pressing `C-\`), the `/` key starts to act as a prefix to enter extended characters.

For example:

- `/o` -> `њ`
- `/a` -> `ќ`
- `/y` -> `ї`

etc...

Is there a way to disable this behavior? I'd prefer to switch it off permanently for all modes, so pressing the `/` always enters the same character independently of what I typed after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean the `cyrillic-translit` input method.

The supported way is to identify each binding with a slash as prefix by looking at `quail/cyrillic.el` and unbind it individually:

```
(quail-defrule "/d" nil "cyrillic-translit")
[...]
(quail-defrule "/t" nil "cyrillic-translit")
```

The unsupported way is to look at quail's code to perform introspection on the input method, find where the slash is defined in its keymap and unset it:

```
(quail-select-package "cyrillic-translit")
(dolist (binding (cdr (quail-map)))
  (when (= (car binding) ?/)
    (setcdr binding nil)))
```

To defer evaluation of that code inside your init file:

```
(with-eval-after-load "leim/quail/cyrillic"
  (quail-select-package "cyrillic-translit")
  (dolist (binding (cdr (quail-map)))
    (when (= (car binding) ?/)
      (setcdr binding nil))))
```

One last issue with this is that there doesn't seem to be any supported way of temporarily working with a quail package. Whether that is a problem in practice, you tell me.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. I have `(setq default-input-method 'cyrillic-yawerty)` in my `init.el` with a couple of customizations

Comment: I successfully unbinded them one-by-one, because the first `qual-select-package` snippet had no effect for me (I tried to evaluate it in a temporary buffer).  Thanks a lot!

Comment: It only worked for me once the method has been defined. For example after evaluating the `with-eval-after-load` block, then using `C-\\` to load the input method.